# C# asp.net check if yes or no buttons is clicked in alert

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if yes or no buttons is clicked in alert,

I created a simple code where the user click a button and an alert shows with yes and no button

so if the user clicked yes "you clicked yes" message will be displayed,

and if the user clicked no"you clicked no" message will be displayed,

its working fine with (no) button but the problem is if I clicked (yes) button for the second time,

"you clicked no" message will be displayed, I don't know why

here is my code:

aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server"
              OnClientClick = "Confirm()"
              OnClick="OnConfirm" 
              Text="Raise Confirm"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs:

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
    //Your logic for OK button
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('you clicked yes'); OpenConfirmDialog();", true);
}
else
{
    //Your logic for cancel button
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('you clicked no'); OpenConfirmDialog();", true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second time, you do not need to create this element again `document.createElement("INPUT");`

Try to give it an ID and check if it is already present.

```
function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.getElementById('confirm_value');

        if (!confirm_value) { //create element only if not found
           confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
           confirm_value.type = "hidden";
           confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
           confirm_value.id = "confirm_value";

           document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }

        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but I have the same issue, when I click the button again it show the message "button no is clicked"

Comment: Are you getting `confirm_value` as selected in the `confirm` box in C# `OnConfirm` method ?

Comment: Also, we need to `appendChild` only once. I have moved that line of code inside `if` block. See if this helps.